# JQuery on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, jquery

What are the business case scenario when JQuery controls are used in CSOM programming in SharePoint 2010? I mean what are business case scenario when JQuery frequently used in SharePoint 2010? 
Which JQuery controls are frequently used?

Comment: You question is very vague and can be answered in a near infinite number of ways. Could you try to make it more specific so that it can be given a specific answer?

Comment: i mean what are business case scenario when JQuery frequently used in SharePoint 2010

Comment: I use jquery in nearly every webpart I create...

Comment: I understand what you mean but I think your question is too vague. I use jQuery in any business case that requires front end development with rich interactions. For me that is nearly every project I do in SharePoint. I suspect those types of answers will not be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is really off!

> The business case of jQuery

- To be able to more rapidly, and effective develop solutions that does anything at all client side. Also jQuery helps you circumvent most of the browser differences when it comes to JavaScript.
- With extensions like SPServices jQuery makes client side developing easier and hence less "buggy".

Personally, I use jQuery for doing the GUI dynamic, and for updating SharePoint items. So, everything you use Javascript for on a "normal" webpage, and a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I use it for variety of reasons custom forms... animations.... displaying data.. charts and data visualizations.